# How to use select into a local variable in SYBASE ASE

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

i am using Sybase ASE 15.0.3. and i want to use this type of logic, but it gives me error.

```
begin
declare 
@b int, @c int

select      @b = Count(My_ID) 
FROM        some_table
WHERE       (some_condition);


select      @c = Count(My_Sales) 
FROM        some_table
WHERE       (some_condition);


insert into my_table (new_id, new_sales) value (@b, @c);

end;
```

and then use these variables to insert value into a table.

ERROR: "Attemp to insert null value into "new_id", table "my_table" column doesn't allow nulls. Update fails"

Comment: What is the value of @b ? Probably there is null.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to prepare your SQL statement before executing it by doing something like:

```
 select @sql='insert into my_table (new_id, new_sales) values ('+convert(varchar(10),@b)+','+convert(varchar(10),@c)+')'
 exec @sql
```

Comment: It gives error: "implicit conversion from datatype 'BIGINT' to 'VARCHAR' is not allowed. use the convert function to run this query" Since one of my variable is BIGINT.

Comment: in the prepared SQL statement, you should convert the variable to varchar(). I corrected my statement above